# How to print out print out only elements of a list containing certain letters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a project and I want to write a code, that would find words containing only certain letters in a sentence and then return them (print them out).

```
sentence = "I am asking a question on Stack Overflow"
lst = []

# this gives me a list of all words in a sentence
change = sentence.split()

# NOTE: I know this isn't correct syntax, but that's basically what I want to do.
lst.append(only words containing "a")
print(lst)
```

Now the part I am struggeling with is, how do I append only words containig letter "a" for example?

Answer (score 3):

you can act like this:

```
words = sentence.split()
lst = [word for word in words if 'a' in word]
print(lst)
# ['am', 'asking', 'a', 'Stack']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this! I hope it's well understood!

```
sentence = "I am asking a question on Stack Overflow"
lst = []

change = sentence.split()
#we are going to check in every word of the sentence, if letter 'a' is in it.
for a in change:
    if 'a' in a:
        print(a+" has an a! ")
        lst.append(a)
print(lst)
```

This will output:

```
['am', 'asking', 'a', 'Stack']
```